# fiber bundle in topological category and smooth category.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $G$ be a Lie group. Denote by $Bun(M,G)$ the set of all equivalent smooth Principal bundle on $M$ with structural group $G$ in smooth category. And denote by $Bun(M,G)_{top}$ the set of all equivalent Principal bundle on $M$ with structural group $G$ in the topological category when $G$ is regard as a topological group. Then we have a natural map  $\varphi:Bun(M,G) \rightarrow Bun(M,G)_{top}$. If $\varphi$ is a bijection and how to prove it ?

Comment: $\varphi$ goes to $Bun(M,G)_{top}$ right?

Comment: Yes ! Thank you .

Comment: [Crossposted on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/q/203209/21564).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. This takes a little bit of theory: you have to know that $G/K$ is contractible for $K$ a maximal compact subgroup. This implies that a $G$ bundle (smooth or no) is equivalent to a $K$ bundle. Now for a compact Lie group $K$ we have a smooth structure on $EK$ and $BK$, which is usually infinite-dimensional, and such that smooth maps to $BK$ classify smooth $K$-bundles. This is constructed via a faithful representation of $K$ on a finite-dimensional space and some theory of direct limits of manifolds.

Now even without finite-dimensionality the usual Sard's theorem implications about smoothability of continuous maps continue to hold. So a continuous equivalence of smooth bundles $E,E'$ corresponds to a homotopy of smooth classifying maps $e,e':M\to BK$ which can be smoothed, making $E,E'$ smoothly equivalent, and a continuous bundle $E$ corresponds to a continuous $e:M\to BK$ which can be smoothed, yielding a continuous isomorphism of $E$ with a smooth bundle.

Comment: Thank you ! How about when $G$ is a disconnected Lie group ?